# Speeds and frames of reference

Tags: reference-frames, speed

When reports state that Voyager is traveling at ~17kmps or that a comet is traveling at 600kmps, what are these numbers relative to? Given that the Earth travels at ~30kmps and orbits the Sun which is traveling at ~25kmps (and so on), is there an implicit qualifier attached to them?

Similarly, when a spacecraft attains escape velocity and leaves Earth (as it were), what would observers, say on Earth, Mars, and Alpha Centauri note as its speed? How about a stationary point between the Milky Way and the Andromeda galaxies?

Comment: In the case of Voyager speed of 17kmps, that is definitely wrt the Sun. Like Alfred Centauri said: it is usually mentioned. But speeds of space-crafts, once outside earth's atmosphere, are usually quoted wrt Sun.
As for the what observers on Alpha Centauri would say: I don't know. I believe Alfred Centauri is actually from there, but he has cleverly avoided that bit.

Comment: @user1218748 So, technically Voyager could, at some point, actually be travelling at 47kmps from Earth?

Comment: @celeopterist, This may sound obvious, but I believe that if at any instant, the Earth and Voyager are moving in opposite directions (velocity vector direction) and are moving at 17 and 30kmps wrt to a heliocentric reference frame, then yes, it could be travelling at 47 kmps from the Earth.

Comment: Let me know if you want this to be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> is there an implicit qualifier attached to them?

Yes, the context is typically enough to make clear the reference to which the speed is relative to.

> Given that the Earth travels at ~30kmps and orbits the Sun which is
>   travelling at ~25kmps

Indeed, in your own question, you have an implicit qualifier when you speak of the speed of the Earth and the Sun.